# ASP.NET CRYSTAL REPORT VIEWER

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I am working on asp.net application (visual studio 2012, .net 4.5 and crystal reports 13 I guess)..

Well I have problem .. I created new blank asp.net page and I used crystal report viewer to display my data from data set..

And intresting is that when I open my page where I should display crystal report data.. page is acctualy blank.. So I Wondering what is problem because everything looks fine..

how it looks in my console, because there are few erros based on crystal reports :
[image]

**ITS ON A LOCALHOST, I DID NOT DEPLOY ANYTHING YET**

Comment: check browser console any error are thrown ?????/

Comment: Yes I got errors in a console...  i will giive you link [HERE](http://postimg.org/image/uj67chphn/)

Comment: Have your issue resolved ?please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem, copy folder asp_config from c:~ and paste it into your project folder, in my case it's located DOCUMENTS->VISUAL STUDIO->PROJECTS->MYPROJECT.. SO PASTE IT IN FOLDER MYPROJECT AND everything will be fine :)

**BUT WHEN I PUBLISH APP I GOT SAME ERROR, FIXED IT ON LOCALHOST BUT ON PUBLISH SAME ERROR** ANYONE COULD HELP ME ABOUT THIS?

Comment: aspnet_client where you placed on server

Comment: Yes, when I publish application on some trial hosting that I take just for testing purposes I can't see report loaded, but I will check that today, we will be in touch : ) I will post news :)